# ZF2 ldap pagination

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I'm having some issues with the LDAP libraries and Active Directory. I cannot search with the LDAP libraries if the parameters will return more than 1000 results, because of the limitations of AD. Also there doesn't seem to be a way to paginate the results using the ZF2 LDAP libraries. I know how to paginate but i would rather use a ZF2 `in-built` method if one exists.

Is there something I'm missing or do I have to create my own method to achieve this?

P.S. I have looked over the manual and the code but i cannot see any methods to achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what i did to get around the issue

```
/**
 * An LDAP search routine for finding information and returning paginated results
 *
 * Options can be either passed as single parameters according to the
 * method signature or as an array with one or more of the following keys
 * - filter
 * - baseDn
 * - scope
 * - attributes
 * - sort
 * - collectionClass
 * - sizelimit
 * - timelimit
 *
 * @param  string|Filter\AbstractFilter|array $filter
 * @param  string|Dn|null                     $basedn
 * @param  array                              $attributes
 * @param  string|null                        $sort
 * @param  string|null                        $collectionClass
 * @param  integer                            $timelimit
 * @param  integer                            $pageSize
 * @return Array
 * @throws Exception\LdapException
 */
public function multiPageSearch(
    $filter, $basedn = null, array $attributes = array(), $sort = null,
    $collectionClass = null, $timelimit = 0, $pageSize = 1000
)
{
    if (is_array($filter)) {
        $options = array_change_key_case($filter, CASE_LOWER);
        foreach ($options as $key => $value) {
            switch ($key) {
                case 'filter':
                case 'basedn':
                case 'scope':
                case 'sort':
                    $$key = $value;
                    break;
                case 'attributes':
                    if (is_array($value)) {
                        $attributes = $value;
                    }
                    break;
                case 'collectionclass':
                    $collectionClass = $value;
                    break;
                case 'sizelimit':
                case 'timelimit':
                    $$key = (int) $value;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    if ($basedn === null) {
        $basedn = $this->getBaseDn();
    } elseif ($basedn instanceof Dn) {
        $basedn = $basedn->toString();
    }

    if ($filter instanceof Filter\AbstractFilter) {
        $filter = $filter->toString();
    }

    $resource = $this->getResource();

    $results = new \ArrayIterator;

    Stdlib\ErrorHandler::start(E_WARNING);
    $cookie = '';
    do {
        ldap_control_paged_result($resource, $pageSize, true, $cookie);

        $result  = ldap_search($resource, $basedn, $filter, $attributes, 0, $pageSize, $timelimit);

        if ($sort !== null && is_string($sort)) {
            $isSorted = ldap_sort($resource, $result, $sort);

            if ($isSorted === false) {
                throw new Exception\LdapException($this, 'sorting: ' . $sort);
            }
        }

        $entries = new \ArrayIterator(ldap_get_entries($resource, $result));

        foreach ($entries as $e) {
            $results[] = $e;
        }

        ldap_control_paged_result_response($resource, $result, $cookie);
    } while($cookie !== null && $cookie != '');
    Stdlib\ErrorHandler::stop();

    if ($results->count() == 0) {
        throw new Exception\LdapException($this, 'searching: ' . $filter);
    }

    return $results;
}
```

This class/method was made to extends the Zend\Ldap\Ldap class, it will allow more than 1000 results to be returned, but it will not return them in the same format as the Ldap::search method.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Zend LDAP Library: Zend\Ldap\Ldap.php

```
/**
 * A global LDAP search routine for finding information.
 *
 * Options can be either passed as single parameters according to the
 * method signature or as an array with one or more of the following keys
 * - filter
 * - baseDn
 * - scope
 * - attributes
 * - sort
 * - collectionClass
 * - sizelimit
 * - timelimit
 *
 * @param  string|Filter\AbstractFilter|array $filter
 * @param  string|Dn|null                     $basedn
 * @param  integer                            $scope
 * @param  array                              $attributes
 * @param  string|null                        $sort
 * @param  string|null                        $collectionClass
 * @param  integer                            $sizelimit
 * @param  integer                            $timelimit
 * @return Collection
 * @throws Exception\LdapException
 */
public function search($filter, $basedn = null, $scope = self::SEARCH_SCOPE_SUB, array $attributes = array(),
                       $sort = null, $collectionClass = null, $sizelimit = 0, $timelimit = 0
)
{
     // ..
}
```

You can see from the signature you can pass in a parameter to limit the resultset.

A very simple wrapper for this method:

```
/**
 * Search for entries.
 * 
 * @parram  string
 * @param   string
 * @param   int
 * @param   int
 * @return  array
 */
public function search($filter, $basedn = null, $scope = \Zend\Ldap\Ldap::SEARCH_SCOPE_SUB, $sizelimit = 0)
{
    $attributes = array(); 
    $sort = null;
    $collectionClass = null;

    $result = $this->_getLdap()
        ->search($filter, $basedn, $scope, $attributes, $sort, $collectionClass, $sizelimit)
    ;

    return $result;
}
```

A simple example to find users could be somethig like this:

```
/**
 * Get all Users..
 * 
 * @param   string
 * @return  \Zend\Ldap\Collection
 */
public function getUsers($baseDn, $sizelimit = 0)
{
    return $this->search('(objectCategory=user)', $baseDn, $sizelimit);
}
```

You could then Use an Iterator Adapter with the Paginator to get this to work correctly:

```
use Zend\Paginator\Adapter\Iterator as IteratorAdapter;
// ..
$users = $this->_getMyLdapService()->getUsers();
$paginator = new Paginator(new IteratorAdapter($users));
```

Comment: thanks for you reply... I don't think this will work if u have more than 1000 results cos i am already doing something very simliar to this and it doesn't. The issue is with Active Directory because it will only return a maximum of 1000 results in any 1 query. If a query needs to return 10000 rows then 90% of the data will be missing. Or maybe im missing something you can explain?

Comment: Truly this does not work for result > server limit. So downvoting